# Como adicionar botão no Maps?

Tags: android, xml, api, google-maps

Selecionei uma activity do Google Maps no momento de criação do projeto, como adiciono esse botão no layout?

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_draw_State"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="11dp" />
```

Layout:

```
<fragment
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/map" tools:context=".MapsActivityWifi"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um layout XML só pode ter apenas uma raiz, logo você deve adequar seu layout, uma sugestão seria:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_draw_State"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="11dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```